# Question regarding Static Initialization Order Fiasco

Tags: c++, static-order-fiasco

I am currently going through the old version of Nicolai Josuttis' book on C++ templates. My question is regarding the initialization of static data members of the `SortTracer` as implemented [here](http://www.josuttis.com/tmplbook/basics/tracer.hpp.html).

Specifically, in `tracer.hpp`, we have:

```
class SortTracer {
  private:
    int value;                // integer value to be sorted
    int generation;           // generation of this tracer
    static long n_created;    // number of constructor calls
    static long n_destroyed;  // number of destructor calls
    static long n_assigned;   // number of assignments
    static long n_compared;   // number of comparisons
    static long n_max_live;   // maximum of existing objects
    ...
}
```

The initialization of the above static data members are done in [`tracer.cpp`](http://www.josuttis.com/tmplbook/basics/tracer.cpp.html):

```
#include "tracer.hpp"

long SortTracer::n_created = 0;
long SortTracer::n_destroyed = 0;
long SortTracer::n_max_live = 0;
long SortTracer::n_assigned = 0;
long SortTracer::n_compared = 0;
```

The test code is [here](http://www.josuttis.com/tmplbook/basics/tracertest.cpp.html):

```
#include "tracer.hpp"
...

int main()
{
    // prepare sample input:
    SortTracer input[] = { 7, 3, 5, 6, 4, 2, 0, 1, 9, 8 };
    ...
}
```

My question / confusion is this: does this program not suffer from [static initialization order fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order) ? (which means, even though the program produces correct results at present, it is due to the fact that the initialization of the static data members in `tracer.cpp` is the same as default initialization)

Comment: I mean, technically you always have it, as that is just a "feature" of the language, but you only see the consequences when your code relies on the order of static initialization.

Comment: I am not sure what potential issue relating to the static initialization order fiasco you imagine could apply here. Can you give an example?

Comment: Well, I may be wrong here, but in `tracertest.cpp`, I am dependent upon the initial values of the static data members of `StaticTracer`. Would I not run into issues if my initial values were something other than zero ?

Comment: @ArnabDe Static initialization occurs before any functions are called. The fiasco occurs when you have static initialization occurring in multiple translation units (and when those initializations are dependent on each other).

Comment: To quote what you linked to, with added emphasis: *"suppose you have two static objects x and y which exist **in separate source files**"*. Another relevant quote from your linked resource: *"the errors often occur before `main()` begins"* -- when does the dependency on the initial values of the static data members occur?

Comment: Do you have a SortTracer object, which is statically initialized or created during static initialization (e.g. inside a function called during static initialization)?

Comment: Well, not yet. I am just studying the examples in the book, as I have mentioned above.

Comment: Then you should have no problem I would say. It is possible to do `SortTracer st = { 4, 5 }; int a = st.dotrace();` as global variables, which both are initialized statically. `dotrace()` as non-static member function would be called before `main()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All global variables (including class-level statics) are guaranteed to be initialized before `main()`. The order in which they are initialized between different source files is undefined.

*Global Initialization Order Fiasco* refers to the situation where global variables in one file are initialized with global variables from another source file, and the result depends on the initialization order. In your case, the variables are initialized with zero, so there is no "fiasco" - the program is safe.